# Identify the number of elements in a python struct/pack fmt string?

Tags: python, struct, binary-data

When using the python struct module on can specify a format string that declares how binary data should be interpreted:

```
>>> from struct import *
>>> fmt = 'hhl'
>>> values = [1,2,3]
>>> blob = pack(fmt, values)
```

It is easily possible to calculate the amount of bytes needed to store an instance of that format:

```
>>> calcsize(fmt)
```

What would be the best way to retrieve the number of variables need to 'fill' a format? Basically this would tell in advance how big the 'values' array should be to perform the pack() in the above example.

```
>>> calcentries(fmt)
3
```

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no such function in the `struct` API, but you can define it yourself without parsing the format string:

```
def calcentries(fmt):
    return len(struct.unpack(fmt, '\0' * struct.calcsize(fmt)))
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Actually, this probably does parse the format string twice. In the actual code I'm going to cache the result.

Comment: @dantje: I meant without implementing the parsing yourself.

Comment: Yeah, understood :-) I continue to be amazed how nice things can be expressed in python.